# Python convert datetime string to date

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I have this string (It's come from a variable. as a example, st_date)

```
'2015-01-28 03:00:00'
```

and I want to parse the date and convert to type:date

```
datetime.date 2015-01-28
```

from it.. How could I do that?

Comment: Docu... https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse ISO formatted date in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-iso-formatted-date-in-python)

Comment: No. My question is about parsing and converting both in same cord. I didn't get correct answer from it.. But I got it from here.. Thank You..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c):

```
import dateutil.parser
dateutil.parser.parse('2015-01-28 03:00:00').date()
>>datetime.date(2015, 1, 28)
```

Comment: Unnecessary - the format is known, no need for an external module. And it's not delivering the desired object type.

Comment: To use extra lib to parse such simple known format is a real overhead. Especially when the standard lib does this.

Answer (score 3):

Use [datetime.strptime()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) which takes two arguments, your date as a string and the format you want.

```
from datetime import datetime
my_date = datetime.strptime('2015-01-28 03:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
my_date.year
>> 2015
```

Comment: This creates a `datetime` object, not a `date` object. Calling `datetime.date(my_date)` would fix that.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
import time
date_str_obj = '2015-01-28 03:00:00'
date_date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str_obj, '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%f')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just read the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

```
from datetime import datetime

a = '2015-01-28 03:00:00'
print datetime.strptime(a[:10], '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the strptime() function.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2015-01-28 03:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') #24-hour clock
datetime.datetime.strptime('2015-01-28 03:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S') #12-hour clock
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [easy_date](https://github.com/ralphavalon/easy_date) to make it easy:

```
import date_converter
my_date = date_converter.string_to_date('2015-01-28 03:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.strptime('2015-01-28 03:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
date.date()
```